# Cartesian product between two queries and remove entries stated on a third one in MS Access via SQL

Tags: sql, performance, ms-access, ms-access-2010

here is my current problem which I hope you could help me out. I'm currently using MS Access 2010 and here is the problem setting:

I have a query [Areas] with a single column Area with values A1, A2, A3, etc.
I have a query [Techs] with a single column Tech with values T1, T2, T3, etc.
I have a query [NotAllowed] with two columns (Area and Tech) which aren't allowed: A1 T2, A2 T2, A2 T3, etc.

I want to create a cross join of all the Areas with the Techs, and then remove the ones that aren't allowed.

```
SELECT a.Area, t.Tech
FROM (SELECT * FROM [Areas] a, [Techs] t)
LEFT OUTER JOIN [NotAllowed]
ON (([NotAllowed].Area = a.Area) AND ([NotAllowed].Tech = t.Tech))
WHERE [NotAllowed].Area IS null;
```

This works by itself

```
SELECT * FROM [Areas] a, [Techs] t
```

It gives "Syntax error in JOIN operation"

MS Access doesn't support CROSS JOIN, if I'm correct. So that's why I'm putting the SELECT * inside the from.

This is much slower and returns an empty table (I was hoping I could not use the NOT IN/NOT EXISTS to speed up the calculation):

```
SELECT a.Area, t.Tech
FROM [Areas] a, [Techs] t
WHERE a.Area NOT IN (SELECT notA.Area FROM [NotAllowed] notA) 
AND t.Tech NOT IN (SELECT notA.Tech FROM [NotAllowed] notA);
```

One solution is to create the first query separately and then reference it, but I was hoping to understand better SQL by solving this in a single table.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Areas] a, [Techs] t)
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [NotAllowed]
                 WHERE ([NotAllowed].Area = a.Area) 
                   AND ([NotAllowed].Tech = t.Tech));
```

---

I am not able to test this is Access myself, but I suspect that your first query would work if you just gave it the Table Alias that is syntactically required of all table-subqueries:

```
SELECT ta.Area, ta.Tech
FROM (SELECT * FROM [Areas] a, [Techs] t) ta
LEFT OUTER JOIN [NotAllowed]
ON (([NotAllowed].Area = ta.Area) AND ([NotAllowed].Tech = ta.Tech))
WHERE [NotAllowed].Area IS null;
```

---

Your second query does not work because the `WHERE` clause conditions are not right:

```
SELECT a.Area, t.Tech
FROM [Areas] a, [Techs] t
WHERE a.Area NOT IN (SELECT notA.Area FROM [NotAllowed] notA) 
AND t.Tech NOT IN (SELECT notA.Tech FROM [NotAllowed] notA);
```

Here, the individual conditions are too general and since they are negatives, conjoining them with `AND` makes it negative under all conditions.

```
SELECT a.Area, t.Tech
FROM [Areas] a, [Techs] t
WHERE a.Area NOT IN (SELECT notA.Area FROM [NotAllowed] notA) 
AND t.Tech NOT IN (SELECT notA.Tech FROM [NotAllowed] notA);
```

As written, it would only accept combinations of Area and Tech that no NotAllowed matched the Area, and no NotAllowed matched the Tech.  Rather what you want is combinations of Area and Tech where no NotAllowed matched *both* the Tech and the Area *at the same time*.  My `NOT EXISTS` query does exactly that, but you could modify your second query to do that also like this:

```
SELECT a.Area, t.Tech
FROM [Areas] a, [Techs] t
WHERE a.Area NOT IN (SELECT notA.Area 
                     FROM  [NotAllowed] notA
                     WHERE  notA.Tech = t.Tech) 
;
```

Reversing Tech and Area in the `WHERE` clause does the same thing.  Note that both of these assume that Area and Tech cannot be `NULL` in [NotAllowed] and must have at least one instance or else you get some unusual logical cases.  In either event, my `NOT EXISTS` version avoids that problem, is a bit simpler and usually runs faster.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly. Could you please explain me what exactly went wrong on the way I tried it and why it didn't work while your solution did? Thanks!

Comment: @Miguel Fair enough.  Expanded explanations have been added.